# button to update main content area

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react by trying to build a simple blog. My goal is to have a list of articles in a sidebar that, upon click, render the clicked article's content in the main content area. Ideally I would take the data from the `data1` object.

I haven't read much about state but from what I know, state should be used if the data is updated/changed somehow and in my case everything seems to be static at this point. Maybe if the list of articles is updated on the go then the list should use a state... Am I correct with this train of thought (conceptually)? Should I use state or I'm on the right track? How to fix my code?

```
var ProjectList = React.createClass({
    renderArticle:function(i){
        //console.log(this.props.data[i])

        return(
            <ProjectContent upd={this.props.data[i]} />
        );
    },
    render:function(){
        //console.log(this.props.data)

        var projectNode = this.props.data.map(function(project, i) {
            return (
                <div onClick={this.renderArticle.bind(this, i)} key={i} className="topicHolder" desc={project.desc}>
                    <div className="topicHolderTitle">{project.title}</div>
                    <div className="topicHolderDate left">{project.date}</div>
                    <div className="topicHolderTag left">{project.tag}</div>
                    <div className="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            );
        },this);

        return(
            <div className="sidebarMenu">
                {projectNode}
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var ProjectContent = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        //console.log(this.props.upd)

        return(
            <div id="mainContentArea">
                <div className="article">
                    <h1>
                        {this.props.upd.title}
                    </h1>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <div className="konec">.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var WholePage = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ProjectList data={this.props.data} />
                <ProjectContent upd={this.props.data} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var data1 = [
    {id: 3, title: "Kindle for geeks", desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet total control", date: '12 Oct 2015',tag:'product1'},
    {id: 1, title: "Kindle for geeks", desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet total control", date: '12 Oct 2015',tag:'product'},
    {id: 2, title: "Tree installation", desc: "Total control sit amet mahmut mamutov", date:'30 Dec 2015',tag:'installation'}
];

ReactDOM.render(<WholePage data={data1} />,document.getElementById('page'));
```

Comment: Hi, @Ando, it looks like there may be some confusion here about how JSX works and how the React render cycle works. If you haven't already, make sure to go through [the React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) to see how it all works; there are [Egghead.io videos](https://egghead.io/series/react-fundamentals) that may help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you can not return `jsx` element from the click handler.

I adjust your code and moved click handler to top level component and pass it as prop. Now when the item is clicked the function updates state on top level component and re renders everything to show details.

```
var ProjectList = React.createClass({

    render:function(){
        //console.log(this.props.data)

        var projectNode = this.props.data.map(function(project, i) {
            return (
                <div onClick={this.props.renderArticle.bind(this, i)} key={i} className="topicHolder" desc={project.desc}>
                    <div className="topicHolderTitle">{project.title}</div>
                    <div className="topicHolderDate left">{project.date}</div>
                    <div className="topicHolderTag left">{project.tag}</div>
                    <div className="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            );
        },this);

        return(
            <div className="sidebarMenu">
                {projectNode}
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var ProjectContent = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        //console.log(this.props.upd)

        return(
            <div id="mainContentArea">
                <div className="article">
                    <h1>
                        {this.props.article.title}
                    </h1>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <div className="konec">.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var WholePage = React.createClass({
    //add state
    getInitialState:function(){
        return {
            article: {}
        };
    },

    //move click handler to here
    renderArticle:function(i){
        console.log(data1[i])

        this.setState({
            article: data1[i]
        });
    },

    render:function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ProjectList data={this.props.data} renderArticle={this.renderArticle} />
                <ProjectContent upd={this.props.data} article={this.state.article} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var data1 = [
    {id: 3, title: "Kindle for geeks", desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet total control", date: '12 Oct 2015',tag:'product1'},
    {id: 1, title: "Kindle for geeks", desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet total control", date: '12 Oct 2015',tag:'product'},
    {id: 2, title: "Tree installation", desc: "Total control sit amet mahmut mamutov", date:'30 Dec 2015',tag:'installation'}
];

ReactDOM.render(<WholePage data={data1} />,document.getElementById('page'));
```